# getting error when export data to csv by using python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, csv

I tried to export data to csv from Mongodb by using Python. I am getting error:                                                                                        "TypeError: can only join an iterable"

mongodb data sample:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51dc52fec0d988a9547b5201"),
  "hiringManagerIds" : [ 
        "529f5ad1030dedd0a88ed7be", 
        "529f5ad1030dedd0a88ed7bf"
    ]
  }
```

Python script:

```
import codecs
import csv
cursor = db.jobs.find( {}, {'_id': 1, 'hiringManagerIds': 1})
with codecs.open('jobs_array.csv', 'w', encoding ='utf-8') as outfile:
    fields = ['_id', 'hiringManagerIds']    
    write = csv.writer(outfile)
    write.writerow(fields)
    for x in cursor:
        write.writerow((x["_id"], u','.join(x.get('hiringManagerIds'))))
```

error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

I want to remove u letters so I use u.join in the script. the hiringManagerIds filed is missing in some document, so I use get. If I don't add u''.join in the script, it works, but it brings u letters in the csv file. I tried many different ways, but it did not work. Appreciate for any helps. thanks.

Comment: What does `print x.get('hiringManagerIds')` do?

Comment: This code would not run: the indentation on the last line of the first block is not correct?

Comment: it gives value of hiringmanagerids: [u'529f5ad1030dedd0a88ed7be', u'529f5ad1030dedd0a88ed7bf']
thanks

Comment: @philip-adler, thanks, when copied to here, I forgot to put space before last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stems from one of the documents not having hiringManagerIds. If this is undefined, at present your code returns `None` into the join method, which requires an iterable (None is not an iterable).

You should check if the key is present in the dictionary first:

```
if 'hiringManagerIds' in x.keys():
    write.writerow((x["_id"], u','.join(x.get('hiringManagerIds'))))
else:
    write.writerow((x["_id"], '')))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. @Philip Adler. It worked. It removes the u letters perfectly.  I like your solution.